# How to draw horizontal line within align and mhchem?

Tags: align, mhchem

No matter what I do, I can't get the line to position properly. `align*` always wants to move it. and i can't use `\noalign`within `\cee`, or perhaps I'm not using it properly (beginner here)? Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article} % [10] =10pt|11pt|12pt
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath} % standard math package 1/3
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem} % insert chem equations
\usepackage[detect-none]{siunitx} % use proper si units
\usepackage{cancel} %strike out text

\begin{document}
  \begin{align*}
    \cee{
      \cancel{\mathrm{MgCl_{2(aq)}}} + \cancel{\mathrm{H_{2}O_{(l)}}} &-> MgO_{(s)} + \cancel{\mathrm{2HCl_{(aq)}}}
      &\Delta H_r&=\SI{105.037}{\kJ\per\mole} \\ 
      Mg_{(s)} + \cancel{\mathrm{2HCl_{(aq)}}} &-> \cancel{\mathrm{MgCl_{2(aq)}}} + \cancel{\mathrm{H_{2(g)}}}
      &\Delta H_r&=\SI{-447.667}{\kJ\per\mole}\\  
      \cancel{\mathrm{H_{2(g)}}} + 1/2O2_{(g)} &-> \cancel{\mathrm{H_{2}O_{(l)}}}
      &\Delta H_r&=\SI{-285.8}{\kJ\per\mole}  \\ 
      \rule{6cm}{1pt} \\
      Mg_{(s)} + 1/2O_{(g)} &-> MgO_{(s)}
    }
  \end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an `\intertext`.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article} % [10] =10pt|11pt|12pt
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath} % standard math package 1/3
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem} % insert chem equations
\usepackage[detect-none]{siunitx} % use proper si units
\usepackage{cancel} %strike out text

\begin{document}
  \begin{align*}
    \cee{
      \cancel{\mathrm{MgCl_{2(aq)}}} + \cancel{\mathrm{H_{2}O_{(l)}}} &-> MgO_{(s)} + \cancel{\mathrm{2HCl_{(aq)}}}
      &\Delta H_r&=\SI{105.037}{\kJ\per\mole} \\
      Mg_{(s)} + \cancel{\mathrm{2HCl_{(aq)}}} &-> \cancel{\mathrm{MgCl_{2(aq)}}} + \cancel{\mathrm{H_{2(g)}}}
      &\Delta H_r&=\SI{-447.667}{\kJ\per\mole}\\
      \cancel{\mathrm{H_{2(g)}}} + 1/2O2_{(g)} &-> \cancel{\mathrm{H_{2}O_{(l)}}}
      &\Delta H_r&=\SI{-285.8}{\kJ\per\mole}}
    \intertext{\centerline{\rule{6cm}{1pt}}}
    \cee{
      Mg_{(s)} + 1/2O_{(g)} &-> MgO_{(s)}
    }
  \end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Otherwise, if you don't want so much spacing, load `mathtools` (which loads `amsmath`) and use `\shortintertext`

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article} % [10] =10pt|11pt|12pt
\usepackage[fleqn]{mathtools} % standard math package 1/3
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem} % insert chem equations
\usepackage[detect-none]{siunitx} % use proper si units
\usepackage{cancel} %strike out text

\begin{document}
  \begin{align*}
    \cee{
      \cancel{\mathrm{MgCl_{2(aq)}}} + \cancel{\mathrm{H_{2}O_{(l)}}} &-> MgO_{(s)} + \cancel{\mathrm{2HCl_{(aq)}}}
      &\Delta H_r&=\SI{105.037}{\kJ\per\mole} \\
      Mg_{(s)} + \cancel{\mathrm{2HCl_{(aq)}}} &-> \cancel{\mathrm{MgCl_{2(aq)}}} + \cancel{\mathrm{H_{2(g)}}}
      &\Delta H_r&=\SI{-447.667}{\kJ\per\mole}\\
      \cancel{\mathrm{H_{2(g)}}} + 1/2O2_{(g)} &-> \cancel{\mathrm{H_{2}O_{(l)}}}
      &\Delta H_r&=\SI{-285.8}{\kJ\per\mole}}
    \shortintertext{\centerline{\rule{6cm}{1pt}}}
    \cee{
      Mg_{(s)} + 1/2O_{(g)} &-> MgO_{(s)}
    }
  \end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Actually I tried something very similar to this and it's fine except it makes a page break right after the line and the final chemical equation appears on the next page. (checking your recent edit now)

Comment: @FarZin This means that there is not enough room for the whole `align*` in the page. Force a manual break if you don't want this behavior.

Answer (score 3):

use

```
  \rlap{\rule{6cm}{1pt}} \\
```

then it has a width of 0pt

[image]

Comment: a width of 0pt? sorry when I replaced my

`\rule{6cm}{1pt} \\' with `\rlap{\rule{6cm}{1pt}} \\' and printed it didn't work. seems like `align' is still moving it

i

Comment: see my edited answer. Should the line be left or right aligned or centered?